# can i be able to extract the structure of a pdf in R to check information such as author, date etc and store this in eg a dataframe?

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, text-mining, pdftotext

i am extracting pdf from a web page and would like to see if it is possible to extract the xml structure of each of these pdfs, and to check for information such as the author, the title of each document, and store this information in a data frame.
I have tried to extract the pdfs as an html just to check if there is a structure (i am just picking at straws here to just check if it works), using xmlParse and then checking the root. i get some results that i can't read.
(I do not have the pdfs locally stored, i have extract them from the website). A An example (with name changes) of what i have done is:

```
htht <- read_html("https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/425885/files/A_RES_55_8-EN.pdf")
textin1 <- htht %>% xmlTreeParse(isHTML = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asTree = TRUE)
textin <- htht %>% xmlParse(isHTML = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE, asTree = TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(textin)


c <- xmlSApply(rootNode,function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
cd.catalog <- as.data.frame(t(c),row.names=NULL)
cd.catalog[1:2,]
```

results shown look like this:

````
Levels: %PDF-1.3\r%âÃ£Ã\u008fÃ\u0093\r\n23 0 obj\r<< \r/Linearized 1 \r/O 25 \r/H [ 1102 245 ] \r/L 132276 \r/E 98654 \r/N 7 \r/T 131698 \r>> \rendobj\r                                                        xref\r23 34 \r0000000016 00000 n\r\n0000001027 00000 n\r\n0000001347 00000 n\r\n0000001554 00000 n\r\n0000001713 00000 n\r\n0000001752 00000 n\r\n0000002318 00000 n\r\n0000002531 00000 n\r\n0000002553 00000 n\r\n0000004632 00000 n\r\n0000004654 00000 n\r\n0000006741 00000 n\r\n0000006763 00000 n\r\n0000008634 00000 n\r\n0000008656 00000 n\r\n0000010299 00000 n\r\n0000010321 00000 n\r\n0000012202 00000 n\r\n0000012422 00000 n\r\n0000012880 00000 n\r\n0000012902 00000 n\r\n0000014764 00000 n\r\n0000014986 00000 n\r\n0000015529 00000 n\r\n0000015551 00000 n\r\n0000018087 00000 n\r\n0000018109 00000 n\r\n0000020629 00000 n\r\n0000023303 00000 n\r\n0000023381 00000 n\r\n0000053714 00000 n\r\n0000075083 00000 n\r\n0000001102 00000 n\r\n0000001326 00000 n\r\ntrailer\r<<\r/Size 57\r/Info 22 0 R \r/Root 24 0 R \r/Prev 131688 \r/ID[<42f182109afbf905f84c217484484e19><42f182109afbf905f84c217484484e19>]\r>>\rstartxref\r0\r%%EOF\r    \r24 0 obj\r<< \r/Type /Catalog \r/Pages 21 0 R \r/PageLabels 20 0 R \r>> \rendobj\r55 0 obj\r<< /S 71 /L 156 /Filter /FlateDecode /Length 56 0 R >> \rstream\r\nHÂ\u0089b```f``Ã±c`e``Â\u009bÃ\u008d Ã\u0088Â\u0080  6PÂ\u0094Â\u0081Ã£Â\u0088Â·Â«Â¤EÂ\u009cÃ\u00899Ã\u0091TÂ¡QÃ\u0083Ã³\nÂ\u0080XÂ\u008aÃ\u0084Ã¸Â\u008bÂ\u0098T:Â\u0094Ã\u00840Â°Â°40(10XÂ\u009e``8ÂµÂ\u0080Â\u0081yaÃ\u00831Ã¦ Â·Â\u0081Â§Ã\u0081QÂ\u0081Â\u0081Ã¥%Â\u0083pÂ\u008bfÃ£Ã±Â´ÂªÂ\u009cÂ²Â\u009b\rPÂ\u0085Ã¿Ã\u009fÃ\u0092L@Ã¬\r` BÃ\u009b4\rendstream\rendobj\r56 0 obj\r133 \rendobj\r25 0 obj\r<< \r/Type /Page \r/Parent 21 0 R \r/Resources 26 0 R \r/Contents [ 31 0 R 33 0 R 35 0 R 37 0 R 39 0 R 43 0 R 47 0 R 49 0 R ] \r/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ] \r/CropBox [ 0 0 612 792 ] \r/Rotate 0 \r>> \rendobj\r26 0 obj\r<< \r/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ] \r/Font << /TT2 28 0 R /TT4 41 0 R /TT6 45 0 R >> \r/ExtGState << /GS1 51 0 R
````

Answer (score 0):

Check the `pdf_text()` function from the `pdftools` package.

Comment: that reads the text of the pdf. i am hoping to get the structure of the pdf like e.g getting the structure of an html page, is it possible to get the structure of a pdf?